# What packages are needed at a minimum for ASP.NET Core MVC (3.1)?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I created a **default (template) ASP.NET Core MVC 3.1** application using Windows 10/Visual Studio 2019.  (background:  I am looking to re-write/convert an ASP.NET MVC 5 web site to Core 3 MVC).

After creating the default ASP.NET Core MVC solution (which I can compile/run), I noticed in NuGet, that **no packages are installed by default**.  I have the following questions:

1)  **How is it that the app compiles/runs, even though no packages, not even Core MVC, are shown in Packages installed?**

2)  For re-writing my app/web site, I will be using MVC, Razor Views, EF Core (using SQL Server, database first approach).  When searching in NuGet, there are many related Microsoft packages.  **What are the minimum packages I must install via NuGet (to get started)?**

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking at which SDK your project file references when you create an empty ASP.NET Core Web Application?

It's [`Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/web-sdk?view=aspnetcore-3.1). This inherits [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/metapackage-app?view=aspnetcore-3.1), and that metapackage references [a whole lot of other packages](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/), amongst others:

- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc (>= 2.2.0 && < 2.3.0)
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor (>= 2.2.0 && < 2.3.0)
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (>= 2.2.6 && < 2.3.0)

So expand the SDKs node under your project, not the Packages node.

Answer (score 1):

In your `csproj` file, you'll note at the top that the `<Project>` tag lists an SDK; the SDK handles inclusion of the ASP NET Core supported packages.

*From [ASP.NET Core Web SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/web-sdk?view=aspnetcore-3.1):*

> Features enabled by using the Web SDK:
>
> - Projects targeting .NET Core 3.0 or later implicitly reference:
>
>   - The ASP.NET Core shared framework.
>   - Analyzers designed for building ASP.NET Core apps.

*From [Microsoft.AspNetCore.App for ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/metapackage-app?view=aspnetcore-3.1):*

> Projects that target the Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web SDK implicitly
>   reference the Microsoft.AspNetCore.App framework.
>
> The ASP.NET Core shared framework:
>
> - Doesn't include third-party dependencies.
> - Includes all supported packages by the ASP.NET Core team.

In order to get started with Entity Framework Core and SQL Server, you can install the specific provider for SQL Server -- `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` should get you there and cascade the dependencies.

*From [Installing Entity Framework Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/install/):*

> To add EF Core to an application, install the NuGet package for the
>   database provider you want to use.
>
> If you're building an ASP.NET Core application, you don't need to
>   install the in-memory and SQL Server providers. Those providers are
>   included in current versions of ASP.NET Core, alongside the EF Core
>   runtime.